# Pdo Mysql : Warning: Packets out of order

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I get the error "Uncaught Exception
  Warning: Packets out of order. Expected 1 received 166. Packet size=52"
when running two PDO queries one after the other.

```
$dbh = new \PDO('mysql:host=' . $dbHost . ';dbname=' . $dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass, array(
            \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true
        ));

$sql = <<<eof
            LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$csv'
             INTO TABLE $table
             FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
             LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
             IGNORE 1 LINES
            ($columns);
            ALTER TABLE $table ADD COLUMN disabled INT DEFAULT 0
eof;
$dbh->query($sql);
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(id) FROM '.$table.' WHERE myfield IS NULL';
$dbh->query($sql);
```

What I'm trying to do : after import of large CSV file (about 30 MB and 40k lines) into database, I want to count how many rows are empty in a field, to fill them in a later query.

I noticed I can run the first query if I comment out the second one, and then I can run the second query if I comment out the first one. If I try to run them one after the other, it fails. I tried raising memory packet to 20M from 8M, and also to set $dbh->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);  with no success. Similar code worked with a smaller dataset earlier. Any pointers very welcome!

Comment: *"I want to count how many rows are empty in a field, to fill them in a later query."* I doubt this has anything to do with your error message, but you don't need to know "how many rows are empty in a field" in order to update them later.

Comment: You're probably right. Though, in this specific situation, it is useful to know the number to batch loop updates. (there can be several thousands to update).

Comment: You should probably handle that with WHERE clauses, not with a loop.

Comment: when changing stuff I have the error "General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other
  unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().
  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you
  may enable query buffering by setting the
  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute." I think the problem has something to do with the problem that you must fetch all rows with pdo or next access to database fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so actually in the eof statement above I had put more than one query. After the load data inline I had added some alter table queries.
It seems pdo can't handle several queries in one eof block.
so I tried separating each query in its own request, and then it worked.

Comment: I had this exact same problem, where I run a LOAD DATA INFILE followed by the creation of a number of indexes. The problem is, when I combine them in one PDO call separated by semi-colons, I get a 500% performance boost versus when I run them as two separate calls. So I really don't want to split these up. Any thoughts about how to proceed?

Comment: FYI, it's not an "eof block". The string for terminating the block can be anything. It's known as a heredoc or nowdoc string, depending on if you have quotes around the identifier. You should try making it `<<<SQL`, because then the syntax highlighting of your IDE might show correctly for the query.

Answer (score 1):

you can add this before fetch all :

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
```

Comment: Yes, with older versions of PHP, and when not using "real" prepared statements.